# Moving existing lambda edge to Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

I have a Lambda Edge attached to a CloudFront distribution. What I want to do is use [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) to publish the lambda (instead of manually uploading files and click on "Deploy to Lambda@Edge"). What I've tried to do, looking at the serverless documentation, is add this yml file to the project and run the deployment script

```
service: cloudfront-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x

functions:
  cfLambda:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - cloudFront:
        eventType: origin-request
        origin: <CloudFront-Origin-ID>
```

This deployed the Lambda but it didn't attached it to CloudFront (it hasn't been published and there is no versions or triggers related). So how can I do this, using an existing CloudFront distribution?

Comment: don't know Serverless but if you are working with AWS why not use Cloudformation ? Their documentation is quite good

Comment: Idk, the dev who wrote the Lambda for some reason decide not to do this, leading now to this kinds of problems. By the way Serverless does exactly this, it creates a CloudFormation stack with the Lambda and the resources you specify in it's config file (for instance I used it to deploy a Lambda function that is attached to an API Gateway. Just set the required arguments in the yaml config file and everything has been created for me. I highly recommend you to check out this framework ;) )

Comment: Agreed, please disregard @hazirovich's comment

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant when using serverless, but as far as I know CloudFront does not yet support nodejs12.x for lambda@edge.

Comment: Yes I found it out, but is unrelated to the issue since it doesn't work with Node10 too :/

Comment: Did you tried serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront plugin https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront

Answer (score 1):

This plugin `@silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge` will not help if you want to use an existing cloud front distribution. It is only helpful if you are going to create a new one.
This [issue](https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge/issues/1#issuecomment-379966146) has been already reported and as per the forum, this functionality they are not supporting.

Comment: This has been my conclusion as well. Currently I'm just using Serverless for an easy push from my repo to lambda, then I just deploy the function to edge by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda@Edge with Serverless-Framework is quite easy. We use this plugin.

```
plugins:
   - '@silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge'
```

Please go directly to the plugin author's website for complete examples: https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge

Comment: I've seen that package but can't find some info on how to use it with an existing distribution. Latest commit is also almost one year ago, roughly when serverless announced support for Lambda Edge, so it might be that this plugin has been merged into the framework itself since it looks very similar at how you set the CF distribution in serverless.yml

Answer (score 0):

Base on your implementation you have a wrong indentation so I think it wont really attach it to your cloudfront. Having a wrong indetation will not create an events on your lambda function so intead of this

```
events:
      - cloudFront:
        eventType: origin-request
        origin: <CloudFront-Origin-ID>
```

Do this:

```
events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: origin-request
          origin: <CloudFront-Origin-ID>
```

I hope that this will solve your problem. Because I encounter this wrong indentation myself and wander why it is not being implemented properly.